# Grails action returning 'errors' property

Tags: spring-mvc, grails

In Grails [reference](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/single.html#REST) there is an example where property `errors` is returned:

```
if(book.hasErrors()) {
    respond book.errors, view:'create' 
}
else {
    …
}
```

In my tests has the same behavior returning 'books.errors' and returning 'books'.

My questions is: why return `book.errors`? and what is the difference between return `book.errors` and return only `book`?